# First order differential equations with 2 varriables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does anybody know how to solve the following differntial equation?

$$w^2\cdot r+\frac{dw}{dt}\cdot r+\frac{dr}{dt}\cdot w=3g$$

where w and r are a function of time so $w(t)$ and $r(t)$.
$g$ is a constant

EDIT:
This equation came from a thought problem of mine which I will now explain since I still do not know how to approach the problem.

Basically I want to design a spiral track in which a vehicle will accelerate. However the total acceleration needs to be constant.

The vehicle will have 2 acceleration components, a radial component ($a_r$) and a change in speed component ($a_s$). Since we want constant acceleration:
$a_r + a_s = constant$

From circular motion we know that $a_r = \omega ^2 r$
where $r$ is the radius, and $\omega$

Further we know that $v=\omega*r$, therefore:
$a_s=\frac{d}{dt}(\omega r)$

For constant acceleration $a_{total} = a_r + a_s = \omega ^2 r + \frac{d}{dt}(\omega r) =constant$

Further usefull information:
Length of the track covered at a certain time
$l=v*t=\omega r t$

With all this the radius will be a function of time, $r(t)$
and the angular velocity will be a function of time, $\omega (t)$

Boundary conditions:
$r(0)  = 0$
$\omega (0) = 0$

Now I would like to find a possible set of solutions to create a track by implementing end boundary conditions that i choose e.g. $v(t_{end})=100 [m/s]$ and $l(t_{end})=5000 [m]$

Here is a diagram for clarity:
[Constant acceleration spiral track](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zl0XG.png)

Comment: One more differential equation is needed to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling $z(t) = w(t) r(t)$ we have

$$
z^2(t)/r(t)+z'(t) =3g
$$

now knowing $r(t)$ you can solve for $z(t)$ recovering $w(t) = z(t)/r(t)$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what if I want to find the combination of w(t) and r(t) for which the equation is true?

Comment: A differential equation is an equation: so think what do you can ask to an equation like $w(t)+r(t) = 3g$ regarding the values for $w(t)$ or $r(t)$ considered as unknowns. This equation (one) with two unknowns would be undecidable.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $w$ is an arbitrary differentiable function. For any such function your equation is a linear differential equation for $r$. Solve it, say, by the variations of constants formula.